# "How to Ask" message seems broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, asking-questions

Here's the "How to Ask" message that appears on the ask question page for MSO when the focus is on the title box:

> ### How to Ask
>
> #### your question about the Stack Overflow engine or family of websites?

I'm sure there's something missing? A link to /questions/ask-advice maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how that happened. Fixed.